# rubber ec2 deployment Duplicate Default security groups

Tags: amazon-ec2, rubber

I am getting this error when i run the command: cap rubber:create_staging

`response_call': Duplicate => the specified rule \"peer: sg-86b557e9, TCP, from port: 1, to port: 65535, ALLOW\" already exists (Fog::Compute::AWS::Error)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/response_parser.rb:26:in`response_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:402:in `response'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:272:in`request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in `error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:292:in`rescue in request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:229:in `request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in`error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:292:in `rescue in request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:229:in`request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in `error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in`error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:292:in`rescue in request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/excon-0.37.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:229:in `request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/xml/sax_parser_connection.rb:35:in`request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/xml.rb:21:in `request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:462:in`_request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:457:in `request'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/authorize_security_group_ingress.rb:49:in`authorize_security_group_ingress'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/fog-1.22.1/lib/fog/aws/models/compute/security_group.rb:102:in `authorize_port_range'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:380:in`add_security_group_rule'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:481:in `block (2 levels) in sync_security_groups'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:476:in`each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:476:in `block in sync_security_groups'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:405:in`each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:405:in `sync_security_groups'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:260:in`setup_security_groups'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:75:in `before_create_instance'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/thread_safe_proxy.rb:13:in`method_missing'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:267:in `block in create_instance'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:266:in `create_instance'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rubber-2.10.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:230:in`block (2 levels) in create_instances'

Comment: did you tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a workaround, although I'm not sure how secure it is.

I went onto my instance and edited the default group. I removed all the inbound rules except for the most basic one. This one I then opened up to anyone:

[image: screenshot]

That seemed to fix the problem.

**UPDATE:** This was fixed in a [recent commit](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/492) to Rubber. I'm currently pointed to the github repo, but you can also wait for 2.10.1 to come out.

Comment: I did try it. It did not work. Rubber configuration error. I shifted to deploying manually